# SQL Order By within Order By

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

So I have two tables, Questions and Answers, joined by a many to many relation table, QuestionsAnswers.  Questions have a Sort column that allows me to control how they are displayed to the user, and QuestionsAnswers also has a sort column that allows me to control the order of the answers for each Question.  My problem is that I am trying to write a SQL query that will select all the Questions and their Answers ordered first by Question.Sort and then by QuestionsAnswers.Sort.  Both sort columns are nullable and integers in these columns should take precedence over nulls.

I can get the Order By Questions.Sort to work fine but once I add in the second sort column, it goes awry.  For instance, if a Question has a Sort = 0 meaning it should be the first Question displayed but does not have any preference for its Answers, it will get ordered below a QuestionsAnswers row that has Questions.Sort = null and QuestionsAnswers.Sort = 0.

Any tips or thoughts if this is even workable would be great.

edit:

```
SELECT
    Q.Id AS QuestionId,
    Q.Name AS Question,
    A.Id AS AnswerId,
    A.Text AS Answer
FROM
    dbo.Questions AS Q
INNER JOIN
    dbo.QuestionsAnswers AS QA
        ON Q.Id = QA.QuestionId
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Answers AS A
        ON QA.AnswerId = A.Id
ORDER BY
    ISNUMERIC(Q.Sort) DESC,
    Q.Sort,
    Q.Id,
    A.Text;
```

Comment: Share your actual SELECT statement, and give a sample of the rows it returns, just enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: `ORDER BY` accepts multiple, comma-separated column names.

Comment: yeah, my problem is that since either of the columns can be null, they will jump over each other in the sort.  I want to completely sort by Questions.Sort and then within each subgroup sort by QuestionsAnswers.Sort

Comment: Use `coalesce` on the columns to give a valid (large) value for `null` columns.  Your current usage of `isnumeric` is making all non-null values equal to `1`, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(Questions.Sort, 999999999), COALESCE(Answers.Sort, 999999999)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works but is it seems a bit hacky.  I mean realistically there will probably never be a sort value that high and I can even limit what the user can input for sort columns to ensure this, but I still feel dirty using it for some reason.

Comment: @rpf3: Agreed, but that's the nature of engineering (as opposed to computer science). Sometimes the leak is best plugged with the chewing gum in your mouth. You might also consider that the technically "correct" solution, `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Questions.Sort IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Questions.Sort, Case WHEN Answers.Sort IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Answers.Sort`, looks hackier than the hack.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see something like this should do the trick. Unless I am misssing something.

```
select questions.*, answers.* 
from questionsanswers qa
inner join questions
    on questions.idquestions = qa.questionid
inner join answers
    on answers.idanswers = qa.answerid
order by isnull(questions.sort), questions.sort, isnull(qa.sort), qa.sort
```